# Exclude/Ignore/Disable flags during do_compiler

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

I am trying to run a script during the do_compile stage of a bitbake (.bb) recipe. The project is built inside an openembedded environment.

1) The script can be successfully run outside the openembedded environment.

2) The script fails when run inside the openembedded environment with the following error:

```
 bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed   -r -o
 bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd: unrecognized option '-Wl,-O1'
```

Openembedded environment is adding these extra flags, -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu.

3) When the script is run outside the openembedded project, this is the output:

```
 bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd  -r -o
```

I am looking for a way to have these linkers, optimization, and other flags disabled or excluded during compile stage. I am struggling to find a solution and I am not well versed in many areas of coding & development.

Is there a statement I can call either inside the script or inside the bitbake (.bb) recipe so that these flags can be skipped or ignored?

Or is there a way I can modify my script to recognize these flags?

Thanks for any information or help. I will be happy to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
do_compile() {
    unset LDFLAGS
    unset CFLAGS
    unset CPPFLAGS
    # remove CC so it is defined here
    sed -e '/^CC\t=/d' -i ${S}/config.mk
    oe_runmake all 

    # fix tools/env Makefile usage
    sed -e 's/$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc/$(CC)/g' \
        -e 's/ln -s /ln -sf /g' \
        -e '/CFLAGS :=/ aCFLAGS += -DMEM_SIZE_${@d.getVar('KERNEL_BOOTLOADER_MEM_SIZE',1) or '128'}MB' \
        -i ${S}/tools/env/Makefile
    oe_runmake env CC="${CC}"
    oe_runmake fw_env_lib CC="${CC}"}
```